# Show specific url path in admin theme

Tags: theming, entities

I want to edit in admin theme some editing pages like "entityform/*/edit". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find what exactly I want.

[Administration theme](https://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module is great for using admin theme selected URL path.